# CAST as Int working in Sybase whereas same doesn't displays output in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to change the data type of a colum type string to int in imapala and show output, it doesn't work for Impala whereas it shows output in Sybased,

The dataset is same.

```
avg(cast(field to Int))
```

Comment: cast(value _as_ datatype) is the ANSI SQL syntax.

Comment: can you confirm what can i use in this case in impala to change data type from string to int and take its average.

Comment: No, I can't. If I could, I'd have written an answer instead of a comment about ANSI SQL syntax. Can't you test it yourself?

Comment: test and tried, nothing worked out , infact float and decimal type are working,

Comment: _"it doesnt works"_ is not a problem description. Why not? What happened? Did you get an error? What was it?